# KonvaJS - Attach fixed scrollbar to element with dynamic height

Tags: konvajs

Please assist, i have created dynamic content and i need attach scrollbar to it.
Main goal: when scroller reach to bottom my dynamic content bottom must be synchronized with it. (bottom  of color boxes must be inline with the scroller)
Scroller size must be the same and don't change height.

How it will be work: if we have 12 boxes for example, slow speed will be used while scroller reach from top to bottom. if 30 boxes for example, it will be faster and so on...
i think so...
Maybe you provide a better solution.

"create dynamic elements layer" section creates color boxes, please check with different quantity

Thank you

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/baxuwfzs/3/)

```
/* move scrollbar and dynamic elements */

verticalBar.on('dragmove', function (e) {

    if (verticalBar.x() != verticalBarBottom.x()) {
        verticalBar.x(verticalBarBottom.x())
    }

    if (verticalBar.y() < verticalBarBottom.y()) {
        verticalBar.y(verticalBarBottom.y());
    }
    if (verticalBar.y() > verticalBarBottom.y() + verticalBarBottom.height() - verticalBar.height()) {
        verticalBar.y(verticalBarBottom.y() + verticalBarBottom.height() - verticalBar.height());
    }
    productsOffset = verticalBar.y() - verticalBarBottom.y();
    productsStep = products.getClientRect().height / verticalBarBottom.height();
    productsStep = products.getClientRect().height / (verticalBarBottom.y() + verticalBarBottom.height());
    newYpos = verticalBarBottom.y() - productPadding;
    newYpos -= productsOffset * productsStep;
    products.y(newYpos);
    products.draw();
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you may need to identify how far your left scrollbar is scrolled. I used `progress` variable (0 <= `progress` <= 1):

```
var progress =  (verticalBar.y() - verticalBarBottom.y()) / (verticalBarBottom.height() - verticalBar.height());
```

Then you may need to identify what is min `y` and max `y` that layer may take to fit into you required view:

```
   var minY = verticalBarBottom.y() + verticalBarBottom.height() - products.getClientRect().height;

   var maxY = verticalBarBottom.y();
```

You may need to adjust these variables of your use case.

So real `y` is just somewhere between `minY` and `maxY` adjusted by `progress`:

```
var y = minY + (1 - progress) * (maxY - minY);
products.y(y);
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ehtro20j/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ehtro20j/6/ i have added responsive logic to the stage and everything is broken (if you resize the window), pls assist back it to normal.

Comment: Since you update stage scale, you need to update `minY` calculation: 
`var minY = verticalBarBottom.y() + verticalBarBottom.height() - products.getClientRect({ relativeTo: stage}).height;`

Comment: woow, i didn't saw it before "relativeTo", very useful parameter. It's also solve any other my issues with scaling after i have applied it to other things. thank you very much!

Comment: hi again, i have added clip functionality, all works good, but not fully compatible with browsers, can you fix it? for example in Microsoft Edge (not really important) and Safari (but this one is important, checked on latest IOS versions) https://jsfiddle.net/ehtro20j/8/

Comment: @EagleSBG please create an issue with the full description here: https://github.com/konvajs/konva/issues